# How to properly match the left join?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm trying to properly match a left-join, where you delete `filter` and information pieces that are recorded in X table for this filter.

### Here is my example:

**table d_category**

```
filter_id
7
8
```

**table d_name**

```
id | filter_id
10 | 7
11 | 7
12 | 7
```

**table product_d**

```
product_id | d_name_id
50         | 10
50         | 11
50         | 12
```

**The Query**

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM product_d
LEFT JOIN d_name ON (product_d.d_name_id = d_name.id) 
WHERE"); // what should this clause be?
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: So when you delete a filter you also want to delete it's match in filter_id AND product_id ?

Comment: i want from table product_d to delete all records where match filter_id because im passing filter_id

Comment: What is wrong with `DELETE FROM product_d
LEFT JOIN d_name ON product_d.d_name_id = d_name.id
WHERE filter_id= $id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for **Cascading Delete**. If that is the case:

If you configure your Foreign Keys to have `cascade delete`, all related data will also get deleted when you delete record from parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

then when you delete building, rooms also get deleted

```
DELETE FROM buildings 
WHERE
  building_no = 2;
```

Comment: so in my case 

CREATE TABLE `product_p` (
  `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `d_name_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (d_name_id)
        REFERENCES d_name (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DELETE FROM d_name 
WHERE
  filter_id = 2;

Comment: I am not sure about your DBMS architecture but it looks ok. If this answer is useful for you please consider to mark it as answer